# trapped by a redstone signal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I got trapped in a position when I had an observer tping people to a position and it's stuck on repeat.  Anybody who joins my LAN gets tpd. How do I remove the observer from almost 100 blocks away? I've tried /fill and don't know the coords and I don't want to abandon the world. It's really important. anybody know anything?